# EF Core - Many-to-Many relationship doesn't work

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm having some problems trying to use the many-to-many relationship in EF Core 2.0. Here is me code:

Here are my entities: 
User

```
 public class User : IdentityUser
{
    private User()
    {
    }

    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<UserCourse> UserCourses { get; private set; }

    public static User Create(string name, string username, string email)
    {
        var instance = new User
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),

        };
        instance.Update(name, username, email);
        return instance;
    }

    public void Update(string name, string username, string email)
    {
        Name = name;
        UserName = username;
        Email = email;
    }

    public void Update(UserCreatingModel model)
    {
        this.UserName = model.Username;

        this.Name = model.Name;

        this.Email = model.Email;
    }

    public void Update(UserCourse userCourse)
    {
        if (UserCourses == null)
        {
            UserCourses = new List<UserCourse>() {userCourse};
        }
        else
        {
            UserCourses.Add(userCourse);
        }
    }
}
```

Course entity

```
 public class Course
{
    private Course() { }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Year { get; private set; }
    public int Semester { get; private set; }
    public List<Lesson> Lessons { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<UserCourse> UserCourses { get; private set; }

    public static Course Create(string name, int year, int semester, List<Lesson> lessons, List<User> professors)
    {
        var instance = new Course { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
        instance.Update(name, year, semester, lessons);
        return instance;
    }

    public static Course Create(string name, int year, int semester)
    {
        var instance = new Course { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
        instance.Update(name, year, semester);
        return instance;
    }



    public void Update(string name, int year, int semester, List<Lesson> lessons)
    {
        Name = name;
        Year = year;
        Semester = semester;
        Lessons = lessons;
    }
    public void Update(string name, int year, int semester)
    {
        Name = name;
        Year = year;
        Semester = semester;
    }

    public void Update(UserCourse userCourse)
    {
        if (UserCourses == null)
        {
            UserCourses = new List<UserCourse>(){userCourse};
        }
        else
        {
            UserCourses.Add(userCourse);
        }
    }

    public void Update(List<Lesson> lessons)
    {
        this.Lessons = lessons;
    }
}
```

Join entity

```
public class UserCourse
{
    private UserCourse() { }

    public string UserId { get; private set; }
    public User User { get; private set; }

    public Guid CourseId { get; private set; }
    public Course Course { get; private set; }

    public static UserCourse CreateUserCourse(string userId, User user, Guid coursId, Course course)
    {
        var instance = new UserCourse
        {
            UserId = userId,
            User = user,
            CourseId = coursId,
            Course = course
        };
        return instance;
    }
}
```

This is my database context

```
 public sealed class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>, IDatabaseContext
{
    public static readonly LoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
        = new LoggerFactory(new[] {new ConsoleLoggerProvider((_, __) => true, true)});

    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory) // Warning: Do not create a new ILoggerFactory instance each time
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

    public new DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserCourse> UserCourses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Lesson>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Course)
            .WithMany(b => b.Lessons)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserCourse>()
            .HasKey(uc => new {uc.UserId, uc.CourseId});

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserCourse>()
            .HasOne(uc => uc.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.UserCourses)
            .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserCourse>()
            .HasOne(uc => uc.Course)
            .WithMany(c => c.UserCourses)
            .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.CourseId);
    }
}
```

This is the repository where I try to add the 2 existing entities user and course to the joining table with the method AddCoursToProfessor

```
public class CoursesRepository : ACrudRepository<Course, Guid>, ICoursesRepository
{
    public CoursesRepository(IDatabaseContext databaseContext) : base(databaseContext)
    {
    }

    public override IReadOnlyList<Course> GetAll() => _databaseContext.Courses.Include(c => c.Lessons).Include(p => p.UserCourses).ToList();

    public override Course GetById(Guid id) 
        => _databaseContext.Courses.Include(c => c.Lessons).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id.Equals(id));

    public void AddCoursToProfessor(string profId, Guid coursId)
    {
        var professor = _databaseContext.Users.Include(u => u.UserCourses).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.Equals(profId));
        var course = GetById(coursId);
        var profCourse = UserCourse.CreateUserCourse(profId, professor, coursId, course);

        professor.Update(profCourse);
        _databaseContext.Users.Update(professor);

        _databaseContext.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

The problem seems to be that when trying to add in the joining table, EF tries to add the course entity into it's table again and I get primary key violation error. I tried different approaches and none of them seem to work. I tried adding directly in UserCourse table but that would try to add both entities into their own tables, I tried deleting the entities before adding them to the join table, that didn't work either. I ran out of ideas, if someone has other ideas, or dealt with similar situations that would be much of help.

I forgot to mention that if I try to add a course by it self or an user, that would work, they both would be added to their tables, so I don't think that the problem is with the DB but with the configuration of the many-to-many relatonship

Comment: .NET Core is the runtime, not the ORM. The ORM is EF Core.

Comment: What's the EF Core version?

Comment: I'm using EF Core 2.0.1

Comment: Your Context has `modelBuilder.Entity<UserCourse>()` twice and `modelBuilder.Entity<User>()` not at all.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I configured the modelBuilder following the model that Microsoft provided.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know here's how I implement a MTM model.

In this instance, there are 3 parameters to take note.

CurrencyPairId is not unique. its a 2-unique parameter.
CurrencyId and IsMain is unique.

This is a trading exchange-styled composite key. i.e. EURUSD

EUR => Main Pair, USD => Counter Pair.

The class

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Partial currency pair.
    /// </summary>
    public class PartialCurrencyPair
    {
        public long CurrencyId { get; set; }

        public long CurrencyPairId { get; set; }

        public bool IsMain { get; set; } = false;

        public CurrencyPair CurrencyPair { get; set; }
        public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    }
```

Currency

```
public class Currency : BaseEntityModel
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PartialCurrencyPair> PartialCurrencyPairs { get; set; }
    }
```

CurrencyPair

```
public class CurrencyPair : BaseEntityModel
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        // =========== RELATIONS ============ //
        public ICollection<PartialCurrencyPair> PartialCurrencyPairs { get; set; }
    }
```

Some of the mappings

in Currency;

```
entity.HasMany(c => c.PartialCurrencyPairs).WithOne(pcp => pcp.Currency).HasForeignKey(pcp => pcp.CurrencyId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

in CurrencyPair

```
        entity.HasMany(cp => cp.PartialCurrencyPairs).WithOne(pcp => pcp.CurrencyPair).HasForeignKey(pcp => pcp.CurrencyPairId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

PartialCurrencyPair

```
builder.Entity<PartialCurrencyPair>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(pcp => new { pcp.CurrencyPairId, pcp.IsMain }).HasName("PartialCurrencyPair_CK_CurrencyPairId_IsMain");
            });
```

Judging by your Course.cs, there's no Collection for UserCourse and why is it static?

Update, 2021 APR 6

EF Core has official documentation for the current practise for implementing MTM.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Comment: Hi, apparently I didn't copy the entire entity for courses (now it's updated). I actually have a Collection for UserCourse, and the Create method is static because I have a private constructor, and I needed a way to create new courses

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so I recently solved the problem. The problem was generated by the GetCourseById method because I was getting the entity AsNoTracking. The entity was not under the EF scope so it tried to create it.